# Unable to run JavaScript from .xhtml file extension; works on .html

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I am unable to run basic javascript functions like `alert` etc. from within an xhtml file. Please see the xhtml file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p id="mytext">Hello World! This is a test.</p>
<input type="button" value="Alert" onClick="displayAlert()" />
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onClick="openAndroidDialog()" />
<input type="button" value="Add highlight" onClick="changeColor()" />

<script language="javascript">
   function showAndroidToast(toast) {
       JSInterface.showToast(toast);
   }

   function openAndroidDialog() {
       JSInterface.openAndroidDialog();
   }

   function callFromActivity(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById("mytext");
        alert(oldHTML);
        var newHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" + msg + "</span>";
        alert(newHTML);
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = newHTML;
   }

   function changeColor() {
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = newHTML;
   }

   function displayAlert() {
        <![CDATA[
        window.alert("I am here!");
        ]]>
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

None of the functions (like ChangeColor etc.) work when rendered on Chrome/Safari browser. Renaming the same file to `*.html` results in all the functions working. I have read a lot of material which has caused me to:
1. Try the `CDATA` tag and put everything in the function into it.
2. Change the mime-type to text/html.

All of this to no avail. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can run javascript functions from within xhtml?

Comment: .html is the extension for xhtml.

Comment: If your `Content-Type` header is correct, then the file extension is meaningless, and your assumption as to what the problem is is incorrect.  This probably means that when you use the file extension `.xhtml`, your `Content-Type` header is incorrect.

Comment: @Lidor: So is .xhtml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `.xhtml` extension, Chrome (WebKit) will assume the media type as `application/xhtml+xml`. With `.html`, the media type is `text/html`.

Now `application/xhtml+xml` is a lot less flexible than `text/html` and your file has invalid markup. When processed as `text/html`, the browser plays nice. When the type is `application/xhtml+xml`, it's not so gentle.

To put it shortly, to work as `.xhtml` you have to make your file valid. There are a lot of mistakes in it (you may check them later [here](http://validator.w3.org/check)), the necessary are:

- Change the `<script language="javascript">`  to  `<script type="text/javascript">`.
- Remove the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` from `displayAlert()` and place them right after/before the `script` tags as comments (`//`):

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  ...
  //]]>
  </script>
  ```
- Finally, there are no `onClick` attributes for XHTML. They are `onclick` (all lowercase). So change them in your `input`s.
- Just so everything is valid, wrap the `input`s in a `div` tag.

Final XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p id="mytext">Hello World! This is a test.</p>
<div>
<input type="button" value="Alert" onclick="displayAlert()" />
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onclick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onclick="openAndroidDialog()" />
<input type="button" value="Add highlight" onclick="changeColor()" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   function showAndroidToast(toast) {
       JSInterface.showToast(toast);
   }

   function openAndroidDialog() {
       JSInterface.openAndroidDialog();
   }

   function callFromActivity(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById("mytext");
        alert(oldHTML);
        var newHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" + msg + "</span>";
        alert(newHTML);
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = newHTML;
   }

   function changeColor() {
        var oldHTML = document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML;
        var newHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = newHTML;
   }

   function displayAlert() {

        window.alert("I am here!");

    }
//]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, but your first sentence is not quite correct. It's not the browser, but the _system_ (the web server or the local OS) that decides what the file type is based on the extension.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks! When the file is served from a server, certainly the mime type is set by the HTTP header. When opening from the file system, though, this seems somewhat fuzzy. Certainly it should be determined by the OS content type mapping, but, for instance, I'm under windows and my `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.xhtml` has the `Content Type` key value of `text/html`, but Chrome (actually, all browsers) still assume the mime type as the more strict `application/xhtml+xml`, hence my statement on the answer. I could rephrase it, should I?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry! I hadn't tested. The thing is, I knew that IE8 won't open XHTML files normally, but it will if you change the registry entry for .xhtml to text/html. So in my arrogance I didn't check, but I assumed that other browsers used that registry entry too. Turns out they don't, they only look at the file extension. So you were right and you shouldn't edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

acdcjunior pointed out that Sriram's original .xhtml file is invalid.  From Sriram's affirmative response, I gather that correcting his syntax solved his problem.

**I, however, present below an example where a perfectly valid .xhtml file fails to execute javascript that instantly works if I change its extension to .html.**

Consider this simple file, which I named hello.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            Hello
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./world.js"></script>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It wants to execute this javascript file, named world.js:

```
document.write(' world');
```

I first note that hello.xhtml validates perfectly on https://validator.w3.org/, so I do not think there is any syntax error.

However, when I load hello.xhtml in Firefox (the current latest prd release, 47.0), it says nothing about there being an error, however, it fails to display the word "world" in the web page.

But if I merely change the file extension to .html, then Firefox loads the page perfectly (the text "hello world" appears).

What's going on?